# How can I change the background color for an specific row properly in a ListView? (Android)

Tags: android, listview, background-color

I have spent some days trying to solve a problem I have with ListViews on Android. I would like to implement a single selection list box using a ListView. So, I would like to have only one row with a predefined light background color and the rest with another preselected color. The problem I have is that when I click over a specific row is another row which is highlighted and not the one I pressed. I added several messages to Log what is happening but all seems to work fine. Here is my code:

```
public class TryListViewActivity extends Activity {
    protected static final int NO_SELECTED_COLOR = 0xFF191919;
    protected static final int SELECTED_COLOR = 0xFF3366CC;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Option 1");
        list.add("Option 2");
        list.add("Option 3");
        list.add("Option 4");
        list.add("Option 5");
        list.add("Option 6");
        list.add("Option 7");
        list.add("Option 8");
        list.add("Option 9");
        list.add("Option 10");
        list.add("Option 11");
        list.add("Option 12");
        list.add("Option 13");
        list.add("Option 14");
        list.add("Option 15");

        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.list_box_entry,
            list
        );
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        // Set the listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    Log.i(
                        "Log",
                        "[SingleSelectionListBox] Item clicked: position="
                        + position + ";id=" + id
                    );

                    // First, set all rows to be unselected
                    int counter  = parent.getCount();
                    Log.i(
                        "Log",
                        "[SingleSelectionListBox] "
                        + counter + " items found inside the parent"
                    );
                    int children = parent.getChildCount();
                    Log.i(
                        "Log",
                        "[SingleSelectionListBox] "
                        + children + " views found inside the parent"
                    );
                    for(int i=0;i<children;i++) {
                        Log.i(
                            "Log",
                            "[SingleSelectionListBox] Child "
                            + i + " has message "
                            + ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(i)).getText()
                        );
                    }

                    // Too inefficient but for now is OK
                    for(int i=0;i<children;i++)
                        parent.getChildAt(i)
                            .setBackgroundColor(NO_SELECTED_COLOR);
                    Log.i("Log",
                        "[SingleSelectionListBox] First visible position: "
                        + parent.getFirstVisiblePosition()
                    );

                    // Set the background color
                    TextView textView = (TextView)(parent.getChildAt(
                        position-parent.getFirstVisiblePosition()));
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOR);
                    Log.i(
                        "Log",
                        "[SingleSelectionListBox] Text inside the "
                        + " View changing the color " + textView.getText()
                    );
                }
            }
        );
        setContentView(listView);
    }
}
```

Inside the resources (res/layout) I inserted a file called list_text_entry.xml with the following content

```xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:padding="10dp" android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

For example, If I click over the "Option 11" entry when the listView has been previously scrolled down until the first row I see is "Option 4", the "Option 7" row appears as selected being the only one carrying a blue color in the background. Can someone explain what happens here to me? I post below the messages I got throw the Log.

```
[SingleSelectionListBox] Item clicked: position=10;id=10
[SingleSelectionListBox] 15 items found inside the parent
[SingleSelectionListBox] 11 views found inside the parent
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 0 has message Option 4
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 1 has message Option 5
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 2 has message Option 6
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 3 has message Option 7
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 4 has message Option 8
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 5 has message Option 9
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 6 has message Option 10
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 7 has message Option 11
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 8 has message Option 12
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 9 has message Option 13
[SingleSelectionListBox] Child 10 has message Option 14
[SingleSelectionListBox] First visible position: 3
[SingleSelectionListBox] Text inside the View changing the color Option 11
```

As I can guess all children inside the ViewGroup as ordered from top to bottom and even when I do this in the code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)(parent.getChildAt(
    position-parent.getFirstVisiblePosition()
));
textView.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOR);
```

Appears the message `Option 11` but is really the `option 7` selected. Is this a bug from Android?

Comment: Next time, please use four whitespaces to markup code instead of using HTML tags. See the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for details.

Answer (score 7):

I have used this code it works nice you should try this:

```
listView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should use as Dave said:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOR);
```

and perhaps

```
view.refreshDrawableState();
```

however because Android recycle lists, it will repeat your selected colour on every first item which is not shown on the screen. So if your screen size can show ten items than 11th,  21nd etc will be also shown as selected when you scroll.

To avoid this you have to create a custom adapter. Then in getView you need to say this:

```
if (myActivity.selectedRow != position){
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
} else {
    v.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOUR);
}
```

Where selectedRow is a `public static int selectedRow` within myActivity, the activity which creates your list. There you store the row number which is selected when clicking the list.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Dave and ChristianB for your answers. I still do not know why Android does it, so the question is still unresolved. However, I found a way to get what I needed creating a custom Adapter. I will give you the code in case someone could need it.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    protected static final int NO_SELECTED_COLOR = 0xFF191919;
    protected static final int SELECTED_COLOR = 0xFF3366CC;

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int viewResourceId;
    private int selectedPosition;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,int resourceId,
        ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(activity,resourceId,list);

        // Sets the layout inflater
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Set a copy of the layout to inflate
        viewResourceId = resourceId;

        // Set a copy of the list
        items = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView;
        if (tv == null) {
            tv = (TextView)mInflater.inflate(viewResourceId, null);
        }
        tv.setText(items.get(position));

        // Change the background color
        if (position==selectedPosition) tv.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOR);
        else tv.setBackgroundColor(NO_SELECTED_COLOR);

        return tv;
    }

    public void setSelected(int position) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }
}
```

So, in the ListView initialization I just need to put this listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        ((CustomAdapter)listAdapter).setSelected(position);
        listView.invalidate();
    }
});
```

This is not an efficient solution due to I am extending from ArrayAdapter which is suppose to have a copy of all data provided. Thus, I am using much more memory than needed and in case the list becomes very large I could have memory trouble. So, if someone knows a better solution, please post!

Comment: Inflating each view is a good solution to this issue. If you are concerned about memory implications (which, unless you're displaying 1,000's of `String`'s, isn't a great concern) you may wish to use `CursorAdapter` instead and store your data in a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the way ListViews number and re-use rows. So, rather than using `parent.getChildAt(i)` to get the row you wish to manipulate, use the `View` object passed to `onItemClick` itself.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOR);
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I regret saying that I tried it before and the result of using directly the View provided in the function is exactly the same. For this reason I tried to found a more complex alternative way, but does not work as well. But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
  @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long   id) 
{

    View v;

    int count = parent.getChildCount();
    v =parent.getChildAt(position);
    parent.requestChildFocus(v, view);  v.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent_button));

            for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if (i!= position)
                {
                    v = parent.getChildAt(i);t  v.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.not_clicked));

                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Basically, create two drawables - one that is transparent, and another that is the desired color. Request focus at the clicked position (int position as defined) and change the color of said row. Then walk through the parent listview, and change all other rows accordingly. This accounts for when a user clicks on the listview multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
   LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.verselayout, parent, false); 
    txttitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Versetxt);
    if (position%2 == 0) {
       txttitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }
 else
       {
    txttitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
       }

     return itemView;
    }
```