# Android: changing background color of listview

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app I am importing the contacts into a listview, trying to change the background color of  list view, I could change the color of whole listview but, I want the color change only for the contacts which have address and rest remain the same.

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) (getContext()
                                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
                        view = inflater.inflate(renderer, null);
                }

                TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                ImageView photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);

                TextView textContNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno);
                TextView textEmailId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailId);

                Profile contact = listCont.get(position);
                text.setText(contact.getName());
                contact.getName();
                contact.getId();

                text.setTag(contact);
                text.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                Profile myContact= (Profile) v.getTag();

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
                        intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
                        intent.putExtra("city", myContact.getCity());
                        intent.putExtra("state", myContact.getState());
                        intent.putExtra("countryName", myContact.getCountryName());
                        intent.putExtra("postalCode", myContact.getPostalCode());
                        intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
                        intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
                        Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 1");
                        activity.setResult(100, intent);

                        activity.finish();
                        Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
                                return false;
                        }
                });



                if(contact.getPhoto() !=null && !contact.getPhoto().equals("")){
                        photo.setImageBitmap(contact.getPhoto());
                }else{
                        photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
                }

                photo.setTag(contact);
                photo.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                Profile myContact= (Profile)v.getTag();

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
                        intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
                        intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
                        intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
                        Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 2");
                        activity.setResult(100, intent);
                        activity.finish();
                        Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
                                return false;
                        }
                });

                textContNo.setText(contact.getNumber());
                textEmailId.setText(contact.getEmail());


                view.setClickable(true);
        view.setTag(contact);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                Profile myContact= (Profile) v.getTag();

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
                        intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
                        intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
                        intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
                        Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 3");
                        activity.setResult(100, intent);
                        activity.finish();
                        Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
                        }
                });

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.profilelayout);
                layout.setTag(contact);
                layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                Profile myContact= (Profile) v.getTag();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
                        intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
                        intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
                        intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
                        intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
                        intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
                        Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 4");
                        activity.setResult(100, intent);
                        activity.finish();
                        Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
                        }
                });


                if (position % 2 == 0)
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape);
                else
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody);
        return view;
    }
```

How to change the color only when I have address for contacts?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4634796/1777090 . Then you can put  a condition for checking whether there is any details or not!

Comment: how to check whether the list row has address associated with it?

Comment: sorry but can you post you complete getView() method

Comment: @nick..here is my complete code http://pastebin.com/D0eMR5x4

Comment: add this immediately after layout.setTag(contact);                 if( !myContact.getAddress().isEmpty() ) 
{
    layout.setBackgroundColor(color)
    //or 
    //layout.setBackgroundDrawable(background)
}

Comment: here mycontact is the tag we set?  =>setTag(contact);

Comment: i did this layout.setTag(contact);

  if( !contact.getAddress().isEmpty() ) 
  {
   
   layout.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.hasaddress);
  }   the app is stopping..itz not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this getView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) (getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        view = inflater.inflate(renderer, null);
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    ImageView photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);

    TextView textContNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno);
    TextView textEmailId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailId);

    Profile contact = listCont.get(position);
    text.setText(contact.getName());
    contact.getName();
    contact.getId();

    text.setTag(contact);
    text.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Profile myContact= (Profile) v.getTag();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
            intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
            intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
            intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
            intent.putExtra("city", myContact.getCity());
            intent.putExtra("state", myContact.getState());
            intent.putExtra("countryName", myContact.getCountryName());
            intent.putExtra("postalCode", myContact.getPostalCode());
            intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
            intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
            intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
            Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 1");
            activity.setResult(100, intent);

            activity.finish();
            Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
            return false;
        }
    });



    if(contact.getPhoto() !=null && !contact.getPhoto().equals("")){
        photo.setImageBitmap(contact.getPhoto());
    }else{
        photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
    }

    photo.setTag(contact);
    photo.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Profile myContact= (Profile)v.getTag();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
            intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
            intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
            intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
            intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
            intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
            intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
            Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 2");
            activity.setResult(100, intent);
            activity.finish();
            Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    textContNo.setText(contact.getNumber());
    textEmailId.setText(contact.getEmail());


    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setTag(contact);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Profile myContact= (Profile) v.getTag();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
            intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
            intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
            intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
            intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
            intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
            intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
            Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 3");
            activity.setResult(100, intent);
            activity.finish();
            Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
        }
    });

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.profilelayout);
    layout.setTag(contact);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Profile myContact= (Profile) v.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("type", profileType);
            intent.putExtra("name", myContact.getName());
            intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myContact.getLandLineNo());
            intent.putExtra("email", myContact.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("contactid", myContact.getId());
            intent.putExtra("address", myContact.getAddress());
            intent.putExtra("website", myContact.getWebSite());
            intent.putExtra("mobileNumber", myContact.getMobileNo());
            Log.d(TAG, "On Activity Result Method : 4");
            activity.setResult(100, intent);
            activity.finish();
            Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
        }
    });


    if (position % 2 == 0)
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape);
    else
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody);

    if (contact.getAddress() == null || contact.getAddress().length == 0){
        view.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.background_dark);  //Set your own color here when address is null
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.background_light);  //Set your own color here when address is present
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: at the end means before the   return view; ?

Comment: Yes. Before return view;

Comment: but getting problem with the braces..itz not allowing...

Comment: Your entire getView should look like the new answer

Comment: getting wrror at myContacts...asking to create variable or field

Comment: the app is stopping the list is not loading

Comment: can u invite to chat..we can discuss there

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21804/discussion-between-sreejith-krishnan-r-and-teekib

Comment: if (position % 2 == 0) 
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape); 
else 
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody); 

if (contact.getAddress() != null && contact.getAddress().length() != 0){ 
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hasaddress); 

} 
return view; 
} 

}

Answer (score 1):

replace the below code

```
 if (position % 2 == 0)
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape);
                else
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody);
```

by

```
if (!contact.getAddress().isEmpty() ){
    view.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.hasaddress);
    }
else
{



     if (position % 2 == 0)
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape);
                    else
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody);
    }
```

-preeya

Comment: where should i add the code?

Comment: add it after  the line layout.setTag(contact);

Comment: i did this layout.setTag(contact); if( !contact.getAddress().isEmpty() ) { layout.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.hasaddress); } the app is stopping..itz not working

Comment: ok. use view instead of layout. And can you tell me why are u using this code if (position % 2 == 0)
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape);
                else
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody);

Comment: Use : if( !myContact.getAddress().isEmpty() ) 
view.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.hasaddress)
}

Comment: its showing error on myContact...

Comment: (position % 2 == 0) using this for giving two diffenert colors row by row

Comment: use contact instead of mycontact : if( !mycontact.getAddress().isEmpty() ) view.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.hasaddress) }

Comment: Let me understand stand this correct . You want to give alternative colors for row  and also high light the row with another color which does not contain address . am i right ???

Comment: yes i already gave alternative colors to row by row and i want give a particular color for the contact with address.

Comment: see the edited answer. This should work .

Comment: getting app closed with the above code..  :(

Comment: getting nullpointer exception

Comment: can you post the exception ??? and plz recheck the annswer.

Comment: here is the log http://pastebin.com/DWx1tk03

Comment: iam getting the contacts but all listrows have same color

Comment: i want the color change only for the row with address..does ur if staement do tht?

Comment: hi sorry...your code also worked ...thank you sooo much preeya

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change any attribute of just certain rows, you need to define either a separate layout for the various rows or in the bindView() method of the ListView, change the attributes you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by adding a color folder in res dir and in color folder define an xml for color and define like this below and save it like anyname.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:color="@color/whiteColor"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/bluetxt"></item> 
</selector>
```

and give the reference of this xml in your defined textview where you are showing Info

Answer (score 0):

declare your own listview along with SimpleAdapter in activities/fragment

```
private ListView myListView;
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
```

find your listview from layout

```
myListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
```

initialize your adapter and bind it to your listview like this

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(myListView.getContext(),
            my_profile_arrayList,
            R.layout.listview_layout_for_the_contact_with_different_color, new String[] { "type",
                    "name", "contactid" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.profile_type,
                    R.id.profile_name,
                    R.id.profile_contactid });

    myListView .setAdapter(adapter);
```

just define your own **listview_layout_for_the_contact_with_different_color**

Comment: i am confused..can u look at my code and tell what i need to change..